# R-markdown datatable incompatible with multiple chunks options set to results='hold'

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

When knitting an .rmd with hidden code chunks, datatable outputs, and setting the options of multiple chunks to `results='hold'`, the output disappears.

Here's a sample .rmd:

````
---
output: 
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
---

```{r}
library(DT)
```

Chunk 1

```{r, results='hold'}
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2),
                  b = c(3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(c = c(5,6),
                  d = c(7,8))
datatable(df1, options=list(dom="t"))
datatable(df2, options=list(dom="t"))
```

Chunk 2

```{r, results='hold'}
df3 <- data.frame(e = c(1,2),
                  f = c(3,4))
df4 <- data.frame(g = c(5,6),
                  h = c(7,8))
datatable(df3, options=list(dom="t"))
datatable(df4, options=list(dom="t"))
```
````

I can get away with setting the first chunk option to `results='hold'`, but once I add that option to the second chunk, the output for both chunks disappears. This seems to be specific to `DT::datatable` outputs; run-of-the-mill unformatted outputs aren't affected.

Comment: What is your desired output? you could also use tabs for your output DT tables

Comment: @DanielJachetta The same problem happens with tabs. In my real code, I have a Level 1 heading, with Chunk 1 and Chunk 2 as tabbed Level 2 headers. (I omitted the tab coding here for simplicity since tabs neither solve nor exacerbate the problem.) I want the tables called in each chunk to display consecutively without the `Code` button between them. My real code has several tables in each chunk, so the output is littered with `Code` buttons.

Comment: The tables aren't long enough to warrant each having its own tab - I want all the tables from each chunk presented together. `results='hold'` spits everything out at once and displays only a single `Code` button, making for a much cleaner output, but presently I can only do that on the first tab. I want to keep the code in the output so the audience can take a look as-needed, but do it in a way that is unobtrusive.